# Is there a bug in Powershell Remoting when reading IIS6 website ServerBindings via WMI?

Tags: powershell, iis-6, wmi, remoting

I am using Powershell Remoting to get a list of websites on IIS6 via WMI (the client machine is Windows 7 64-bit and the server is Windows 2003)

The problem is that following does not work:

```
$websites = Invoke-Command -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -UseSSL { Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2' -Class IISWebServerSetting }

$websites[0].ServerBindings[0].Port
```

Port is `$null`, but

```
$websites[0].ServerBindings.Count
```

returns `1`

I can use this workaround, but it's not conveniant:

```
$websites = Invoke-Command -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -UseSSL {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2' -Class IISWebServerSetting |
    Select-Object ServerComment, @{
        Name="ServerBindingPorts"; Expression = 
        {
            $ports = @(); 
            foreach ($tmpServerBinding in $_.ServerBindings) 
            {
                $ports += $tmpServerBinding.Port 
            }; 
            return $ports; 
        }
    },@{
        Name="SecureBindingPorts"; Expression = 
        {
            $ports = @(); 
            foreach ($tmpSecureBinding in $_.SecureBindings) 
            {
                $ports += $tmpSecureBinding.Port 
            }; 
            return $ports; 
        }
    }
}
```

then I can just get ports this way:

```
$websites[0].ServerBindingPorts
```

I have the same problem with `SecureBindings` property.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
I'm am powershell newbie but I did google for a few hours and found no answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

WMI and the WMI cmdlets already do remoting, that's the `-server` parameter on `Get-WMIObject` so your:

> ```
> $websites = Invoke-Command -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -UseSSL { Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2' -Class IISWebServerSetting }
> ```

can be done equally with:

```
$websites = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SEVER_NAME -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftIISv2' -Class IISWebServerSetting
```

This will avoid needing to go through the WS-MAN remoting serialiser, which may well help.

Also:

> Port is $null

What is `Port`? There is no `Port` property on [`IIsWebServerSetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524332%28VS.90%29.aspx).

And also your custom property expression is very complicated:

```
@{
    Name="SecureBindingPorts"; Expression = 
    {
        $ports = @(); 
        foreach ($tmpSecureBinding in $_.SecureBindings) 
        {
            $ports += $tmpSecureBinding.Port 
        }; 
        return $ports; 
    }
}
```

Rather better to use PowerShell's ability to process lists with pipelines:

```
@{Name="SecureBindingPorts"; Expression = { @($_.SecureBindings | %{ $_.Port }) }}
```

where I'm using `@(...)` to ensure I always get a collection even if there are zero or one objects in the `SecureBindings` property.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the direct WMI try. As for Port the $websites[0].ServerBindings[0].Port is $null and ServerBidnings[0] has such property. And regarding processings lists with pipelines, thanks for that - I was sure there must be some shortcut but as I said am still a Powershell newbie :)

Comment: The direct WMI call to the server gives me "Access denied". I'm not sure I wan to open another remote channel to my server, that's why I decided to use Powershell Remoting. Do you know how to make PS Remoting + WMI + IIS6 work the way it should?

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak WMI Access Denied is DCOM permissions (the error if DCOM blocked otherwisde, eg. by firewall, is different). Re. `Port` being null I would start by looking at the way WMI is self describing (starting with what is the type of members of `SecureBindings`). As I don't have IIS6 running anywhere I can't try thatehere.